# Crystal report show group from the second page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report with a group, but on the first page there is general information and I want the records of the group to be shown from the second page. Currently the group starts on the first page, how can I start the second page?

With the below, does not show the group on the first page but on the second page does not show the first group records. That is, the group starts on the first page only that hides the records, I want the group to start on the second page.

Report Header

Page Headers

GroupHeader (suppress if = first page)

Details

GroupFooter

Report Footer

Page Footer

Thanks

Comment: Please add a code snippet of what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a page 2 pages for formatting.

In that case, do the following :

1. Open the report in Design View
2. Right click on the Page Footer section and select Section Expert
3. Make sure the Page Footer section is selected in the Section Expert dialog box.
4. Check the box that says "New Page After"
5. Click Save and Close and then click OK.

Comment: My intention is to show on the first page a table with reduced information of 3 clients. And from the second page to page 4, show detailed information of each client that is on the first page. My problem is that the detailed information shows it from the first page, I want it to be from the second page. Sorry my English is not very good, tell me if you understand what I'm asking

Comment: You likely need to use subreports.